# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n^2 x^2)}{n^3}$ converges uniformly on R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n^2 x^2)}{n^3}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

How should I start? Weierstrass M-test or prove it's uniformly Cauchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\left\vert\frac{\sin(n^2 x^2)}{n^3}\right\vert\leq\frac{1}{n^3}
$$

Comment: so m test, since $\sum$ 1/n^3 converges right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: which implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n^2 x^2)}{n^3}$ converges uniformly by M test

Comment: Yes, that's how the M-test works.